Join columns by rows for each time step
my dataframe is as follows and I would like to rearrange, update and save it to csv or similar format.

 time         lat   lon    ws        wd
1/1/2023 0:00 -5    107    8.214895  313.9049
1/1/2023 0:00 -5    107.25 8.351197  314.44873
1/1/2023 0:00 -5.25 107    7.6247864 307.61456

1/1/2023 1:00 -5    107    8.084728  310.0435
1/1/2023 1:00 -5    107.25 8.091071  308.73547
1/1/2023 1:00 -5.25 107    7.4219675 302.27475

1/1/2023 2:00 -5    107.25 7.8656287 304.08533
1/1/2023 2:00 -5    107.5  8.087259  300.91684
1/1/2023 2:00 -5.25 107    7.4953856 300.94644

Desired df:
time  ws        wd        ws       wd        ws        wd
0     8.214895  313.9049  8.351197 314.44873 7.6247864 307.61456
3600  8.084728  310.0435  8.091071 308.73547 7.4219675 302.27475
7200  7.8656287 304.08533 8.087259 300.91684 7.4953856 300.94644

Group all ws wd in one row for each time step. One time step is 1h (3600s), 24 rows for one day, and the next day will be 25h, 26h (90000s, 93600s and so on).
I have tried stack, unstack, pivot, but may be missing something.
I would appreciate your sugesstion. Thank you.

Can you provide some small reproducible data?

Hi, thank you. I have updated it. The location (latitude,longitude) is also included in data but time index is most important.

The df in your image has multiple dates. Do you want to group all ws and wd values per time step regardless of the date, or should the time step cross days? If you don't want to group, but time step resets for each day, do you want a date added before the time step? Regardless of the answer, please add the updated desired output to your Q as text, and make it the actual desired output based on your textual input sample.

Yes, group all ws wd in one row for each time step. One time step is 1h (3600s), 24 rows for one day, and the next day will be 25h, 26h (90000s, 93600s and so on). I have edited the desired output. Please check it out and thank you.

Convert column time to datetimes and subtract minimal value for timedeltas, for seconds use Series.dt.total_seconds, then create counter by GroupBy.cumcount and pivot by DataFrame.pivot, last sorting output with flatten MultiIndex for prevent duplicated columns names:
times = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df['time'] = times.sub(times.min()).dt.total_seconds().astype(int)

out = (df.assign(g = df.groupby('time').cumcount())
        .pivot(index='time', values=['ws','wd'], columns='g')
        .sort_index(level=[1, 0], axis=1, ascending=[True, False]))

out.columns = out.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}')
print (out)
          ws_0       wd_0      ws_1       wd_1      ws_2       wd_2
time                                                               
0     8.214895  313.90490  8.351197  314.44873  7.624786  307.61456
3600  8.084728  310.04350  8.091071  308.73547  7.421968  302.27475
7200  7.865629  304.08533  8.087259  300.91684  7.495386  300.94644

